# Panel components moves after rolling up the frame

Tags: java, swing, awt, paintcomponent

I have such code, where I need to create some buttoms for customizing the square. It works, but after rolling up the frame the text field moves all over the frame and I don't know why. I mean when I execute the programm for first it's located in the right position that I mentioned using method setBounds(), but then it's located above the square. So how can I fix it?

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.text.AttributedString;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;

     public class Square extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

      Button butt1 = new Button("Fill with yellow");
      Button butt2 = new Button("Fill with red");
      Button butt3 = new Button("Add label");
      Button butt4 = new Button("");

      Pan contentPane = new Pan();


      public Square() {
        super("Square");
        this.setBounds(200, 100, 670, 400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.getContentPane().add(contentPane);
        contentPane.setBounds(0, 0, 670, 275);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        add(butt1);
        butt1.setBounds(25, 300, 190, 25);
        butt1.addActionListener(this);
        add(butt2);
        butt2.setBounds(235, 300, 190, 25);
        butt2.addActionListener(this);
        butt3.setBounds(440, 300, 190, 25);
        butt3.addActionListener(this);
        add(butt3);
        add(butt4);

      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object o = e.getSource();
        if (o == butt1) {
            contentPane.draw(1);
        }
        else if (o == butt2) {
            contentPane.draw(2);
        }
        else if (o == butt3) {
            contentPane.draw(3);
        }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          Square w = new Square();
        w.setVisible(true);
      }
    }

    class Pan extends JPanel {
      Graphics g;
      Graphics2D g2;
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.drawRect(240, 70, 150, 150);  
        }

      public void draw(int i) {

          g = getGraphics();
          super.paintComponent(g);
          g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
         switch(i) {
        case 1: g2.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g2.fillRect(240, 70, 150, 150); 
            break;
        case 2: g2.setColor(Color.red);
            g2.fillRect(240, 70, 150, 150); 
            break;
        case 3:
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.drawRect(240, 70, 150, 150);   
            JTextField text = new JTextField(25);
            this.add(text);
            Button add = new Button("Add");
            add.setBounds(400, 230, 120, 25);
            this.add(add);
            text.setBounds(240, 230, 150, 25);

            Font font = new Font("Veranda", Font.BOLD|Font.ITALIC, 24);
                class AddButton extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                        AttributedString label = new AttributedString(text.getText());  
                        label.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, font);
                        label.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.PINK);
                        g2.drawString(label.getIterator(), 240, 50);    
                    }
                }   
            AddButton listener = new AddButton();
            add.addActionListener(listener);
            break;
         }

         }
    }
```

Comment: `g = getGraphics();` is a bad idea on many levels. Calling `super.paintComponent(g);` outside of a paint pass is also a bad idea.  This is NOT how custom painting should be done. Start by having a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for how painting works and how you should work with it

Comment: And mixing heavy weight (AWT) components with light weight (Swing) components is also going to give you issue

Answer (score 1):

Okay lots of core issues and misunderstandings.

Swing uses layout managers.  This is probably one of the first things you're butting heads again. Layout managers make decisions about how best to position components based on their individual algorithms.

Start by taking a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details and make good use of them.  GUIs are complex and dynamic things, with many factors going in to determining how components should be sized and positioned.

Painting.  Another problem new developers have is understanding that they don't control the paint system.  Swing uses a passive rendering system, which means it will paint when it feels its required.

You can provide hints when a new paint pass should be done by calling `repaint`, but it's up to the system to decide what and when something should be painted.

`g = getGraphics();` is a bad idea on many levels. Apart from been able to return `null`, it's nothing more then a snapshot of the last paint pass and will be discarded when a new paint pass occurs.

Calling `super.paintComponent(g);` outside of a paint pass is also a bad idea.  In fact, there should rarely ever be a need to call any of the paint methods directly.

This is NOT how custom painting should be done. Start by having a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for how painting works and how you should work with it

Also, mixing heavy weight (AWT) and light weight (Swing) components together is generally a bad idea should be avoid as much as possible.

## Example...

So, I "hacked" you example into something a "little" more reasonable

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;
import java.text.AttributedString;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Square extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton butt1 = new JButton("Fill with yellow");
    JButton butt2 = new JButton("Fill with red");
    JButton butt3 = new JButton("Add label");
    JButton butt4 = new JButton("");

    Pan contentPane = new Pan();

    public Square() {
        super("Square");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.getContentPane().add(contentPane);
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        JPanel actions = new JPanel();
        actions.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        actions.add(butt1);
        butt1.addActionListener(this);
        actions.add(butt2);
        butt2.addActionListener(this);
        butt3.addActionListener(this);
        actions.add(butt3);
//      actions.add(butt4);

        add(actions, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object o = e.getSource();
        if (o == butt1) {
            contentPane.draw(1);
        } else if (o == butt2) {
            contentPane.draw(2);
        } else if (o == butt3) {
            contentPane.draw(3);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Square w = new Square();
        w.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Pan extends JPanel {

    private int state = -1;
    private String text = null;

    public Pan() {
        Font font = new Font("Veranda", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 24);
        setFont(font);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(670, 275);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g2.drawRect(240, 70, 150, 150);
        switch (state) {
            case 1:
                g2.setColor(Color.yellow);
                g2.fillRect(240, 70, 150, 150);
                break;
            case 2:
                g2.setColor(Color.red);
                g2.fillRect(240, 70, 150, 150);
                break;
            case 3:
                g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                g.drawRect(240, 70, 150, 150);
                break;
        }

        if (text != null) {
            AttributedString label = new AttributedString(text);
            label.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FONT, getFont());
            label.addAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND, Color.PINK);
            g2.drawString(label.getIterator(), 240, 50);
        }
    }

    public void draw(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 3:
                JTextField textField = new JTextField(25);
                JButton add = new JButton("Add");

                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                gbc.weighty = 1;
                gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;

                this.add(textField, gbc);
                gbc.gridx++;
                this.add(add, gbc);

                add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                        text = textField.getText();
                        remove(textField);
                        remove(add);

                        revalidate();
                        repaint();
                    }
                });

                revalidate();
                repaint();

                break;
        }
        state = i;
        repaint();

    }
}
```

[image: Magic numbers]

Your code is full of, what is commonly known as, "magic numbers".  These are values whose meaning is unknown.

Run the code and try resizing the window and you will see what I mean.  Instead, you should be relying on "known" values, like `getWidth` and `getHeight` to make better determinations about how you should render the output